# IIS server stopped and gives an error about kerbauth.dll , how to solve it?

Tags: asp.net, sqlite, iis

I try my published asp.net project files on local iis in win7 , it works fine , but i gives an error on web server  :

" Also i use sqlite 3 "

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might find the answer to your problem here: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/rakkimk/archive/2007/11/03/iis7-running-32-bit-and-64-bit-asp-net-versions-at-the-same-time-on-different-worker-processes.aspx

Apparently, your have a 32-bit web app running on your IIS, which is not configured to run 32-bit web apps.